# Core Service Client lack of robustness in Workflow

Tags: core-service, workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1, hotfixes

I was recently asked "*that hotfix looks pretty much the same as this problem we have here - should we just try it?*".

The challenge we've encountered is increasing timeouts (even with increased timeout params to a reasonable level) whilst calling some heavy/frequent core service calls in dealing with some business rules and the TMS, and the hotfix referred to is Hotfix TT88696.

I see the hotfix (details noted below) actually infers the Core Service Client handling by workflow could be improved (See "*Improved robustness of handling of Core Service clients by the workflow agent*")

Whilst I accept the hotfix specifics are for an issue where the CMS becomes unresponsive - I think the question is valid given it would appear that it's application will make the very thing we're seeing as a problem "more robust"  (if there are no conflicts with other hotfixes).

The question - there has to be a question - is - is it ill-advised to try the hotfix and if it works run with it?

> Release Notes for Hotfix TT88696
>
> Version:  This hotfix is intended for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1.
>
> Problem description: Content Manager system becomes unresponsive when
>   many bundle workflow activities are resumed.
>
> Hotfix description: Improved robustness of handling of Core Service
>   clients by the workflow agent, also ensured proper cleanup when
>   workflow scripts fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a think about this and would propose the answer is

- Don't apply a hotfix without understanding (or agreeing with Support)
  that it will fix the **exact issue** you're seeing

  - You may, on the front of it, see something similar but the fix could
    be a whole world of difference!
- Remember that hotfixes are not 'designed' to *work together*

  - they are
    designed to fix a problem - when you have a number of hotfixes to
    apply there is the risk that some other hotfix file/stored proc etc. gets
    overridden

I think as professionals, advising clients, it makes sense that we are aware of similar problems that have hotfixes but - our advice should really be to check-in with the source of the hotfix against the *similar* issue we encounter before "chancing" that it fits.

The way I've done this recently was to include a reference to the 'possibly related' hotfix to the other (Core Service/Workflow) related ticket the client has open with Tridion Support.